# Адаптивная карусель на не адаптивном сайте

Tags: jquery, responsive, bxslider

Суть проблемы: сайт не адаптивный http://noiramsk.ru соответственно мета тега viewport нет, и все бы ничего, но таблицы в bxslider http://prntscr.com/ewa0is отображаются не корректно на на мобиле, и попытки сделать на мобиле один слайд вместо двух свелись к нулю так как никто не видит реальных размеров окна, прописать viewport вообще не вариант так как вся верстка едет на сайте. Какие есть варианты решения проблемы? возможно ли как-то только для карусели показать размер экрана?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение, `screen.width` показывает размер экрана без `viewport`, соответственно условие успешно срабатывает

```
if (screen.width <= '500') {  
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({ 
minSlides: 1, 
maxSlides: 1
});
```

Comment: `alert($(window).width());` отлично работает. После изменения размера окна браузера, обновите страницу, будет показан текущий размер.